# ASP.net MVC 5 TLS 1.2 (chrome warning about TLS 1.0 deprecated)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iis, tls1.2

after deploying an asp.net mvc5 website to a shared hosting (plesk panel) with `let's encrypt ssl` I see this warning in the chrome console:

> The connection used to load resources from https://example.com used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, which are deprecated and will be disabled in the future. Once disabled, users will be prevented from loading these resources. The server should enable TLS 1.2 or later. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5654791610957824 for more information.

is this something that can be fixed in the code of the application, or is it server configuration ?

Comment: It is purely a server configuration. Ask your host provider to work on that.

Comment: they fixed it, it was a server problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from comment with some additional info.

The message from Chrome is clear enough,

1. Chrome attempts to use TLS 1.2 for security (TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not considered secure).
2. The server side does not support TLS 1.2 handshakes as Chrome detects.

Therefore, only the server administrators (or service providers ISP) can diagnose and fix such issues.